# Customizing Community with html header

Tags: html, community, header

I am customizing community (VF + tabs) and whenever I add html header in the community, default user options on right hand side are not longer available.

Is there a way to use html header with all user options like My settings, logout still available?

Thanks

Comment: have you added `applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false"` in apex:page ?

Comment: I am using a combination of standard and custom vf pages for the community

Comment: Can you share your vf code of what you are trying?